# How to fix Xpath Operators problem in python xml parsing

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm trying to find the days where the maxtemp is greater than 0. However,the following code gives me a empty list.

I tried using an example on w3schools xpath exmaples where it finds the tittle of books that are priced over 35.

Example:
    /bookstore/book[price>35]/title

xml:

```
<bookstore>

<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

This is the code and xml file I'm trying to work with:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
tree = ET.parse('SaintJohn.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
list=root.findall('.//stationdata[maxtemp>0]/maxtemp')
for i in list:
    print(i.text)
```

This is the XML file:

```
<climate>
<stationdata day="1" month="1" year="2019">
<maxtemp description="Maximum Temperature" 
units="°C">1.9</maxtemp><mintemp description="Minimum Temperature" 
units="°C">-10.6</mintemp><meantemp description="Mean Temperature" 
units="°C">-4.4</meantemp><heatdegdays description="Heating Degree 
Days" units="°C">22.4</heatdegdays>
</stationdata>
<stationdata day="2" month="1" year="2019"><maxtemp 
description="Maximum Temperature" units="°C">-10.6</maxtemp> 
<mintemp description="Minimum Temperature" 
units="°C">-22.4</mintemp><meantemp description="Mean Temperature" 
units="°C">-16.5</meantemp><heatdegdays description="Heating 
Degree Days" units="°C">34.5</heatdegdays></stationdata>
</climate>
```

I would like just one item in the list.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using lxml:

```
temp = [your xml above]

from lxml import html
root = html.fromstring(temp)

list = root.xpath('.//stationdata/maxtemp[text()>0]')
for i in list:
    print(i.text)
```

Output:

> 1.9